# Is there a working alternative to if(struct == null)?

Tags: c#, struct

I'm trying to check if a struct from an array has been assigned, I can't check it or it's data for null. Is there a way I can check if it has been assigned yet?

Struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    public struct CharInfo
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public CharUnion Char;
        [FieldOffset(2)]
        public short Attributes;
    }
```

Method

```
    public void render(){
        for (int i = 0; i < (width * height - 1); i++) {
            if (screenBuffer[i].Char.UnicodeChar != Convert.ToChar(" ")) {
                ScreenDriver.screenBuffer[i] = screenBuffer[i];
            }
        }
       // ScreenDriver.screenBuffer = screenBuffer;
    }
```

Comment: You could define `screenBuffer` as array of `Nullable<CharInfo>`.

Comment: Compare it to default(CharInfo) or convert it to a nullable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673440/how-can-i-check-whether-a-struct-has-been-instantiated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I check whether a struct has been instantiated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673440/how-can-i-check-whether-a-struct-has-been-instantiated)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can compare the struct to its default value: `if (struct==default(CharInfo)`. However this cannot differentiate between an uninitialized struct and a struct initialized with zeroes. This is because there are no such things as uninitialized structs, a struct is always automatically initialized.

If you can extend the struct, you can give it a `bool IsAssigned`. Default initialization will set this to false. Another option is to wrap it in a nullable:
`CharInfo?[] screenBufferWithNull = new CharInfo?[123];`

If extending the struct, or replacing it with a `nullable<struct>` is not desired, and you want to keep an aray of structs as in your example, the easiest workaround is to keep this information in a separate array of bools:
`bool[] screenbufferIsAssigned = new bool[screenbuffer.Length];`

Comment: Another option is to have an item in the enumeration be very specifically not initialized. For example enum Test { NotIntialized = 0, Red, Green, Blue }. the value 0 is the default.

Answer (score 1):

Structs cannot be null as they are value types. Instead you can compare the to its default value using `default(CharInfo)` or create a Nullable.

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting a new error. "Error 2 Operator '!=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'SharpTUI.Krn32.Kernal32.CharInfo' and 'SharpTUI.Krn32.Kernal32.CharInfo' "

Comment: Thats because you need to overload the operators for your struct as seen in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199026/comparing-two-structs-using

Answer (score 0):

In the following code, we create and implement an `implicit boolean operator` that handles one approach to determining if a `struct` has been initialized (a `struct` is **never** `null`, as they are value types. However their members **can** be `null`).

```
struct Foo
{
    float x;
    public static implicit operator bool(Foo x)
    {
        return !x.Equals(default(Foo));
    }
}
```

**Note:** *this will return a false negative when `x == 0`. Keeping this in mind, you can creatively code a workaround depending on your specific needs.*

The simplest work around would be to create a *dummy class* (eg `nullable`) which you initialize in the constructor of the `struct`, and ensure to always initialize said `struct` through the use of a constructor:

```
public class nullable{}
struct Foo
{
    nullable n;
    float x;
    public Foo(float x)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.n = new nullable();
    }
    public static implicit operator bool(Foo x)
    {
        return !x.Equals(default(Foo));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if(mFoo)
{
    //Do something
}
```