# How to ignore "Use of possibly unassigned field 'field'"?

Tags: c#, struct

I have the following minimal example code:

```c#
struct MyStruct 
{
    long Size;
}

MyStruct myStruct;
bool result;

if (someCondition)
{
    result = API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct); // the call will set 'result' to 'true' and assign a value to 'myStruct'
}
if (result)
{
    result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct); //  <-- gives error "Use of possibly unassigned field 'myStruct' (CS0170)"
}
```

I know that `myStruct` has been assigned a value when I'm trying to use the struct for the second API call. The API is delivered by a third party and I cannot change it. Is there any way I can ignore the error that my field is possibly undefined?

I know there are some similar questions out there e.g. [How to check if a struct has been instanciated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12673440/how-can-i-check-whether-a-struct-has-been-instantiated), but the solution there is to use a nullable struct and that is not an option for me as the API will not accept a nullable struct.

Comment: If it's as simple as this, is assigning a dummy value to the struct out of the question?

Comment: You have different options. Dummy value is one of them as pointed out by Damien. I think that since the struct is only set if someCondition is true and there isn't any other meaningful value you can assign, then your second if should probably be inside your first if. This way the compiler can be sure that your struct has been set. Otherwise you will need a default value. Yet another way would be to make a guard of the first if(inverse bool logic and abort execution if false. Then you can call the first API Method after the guard.

Comment: This kind of only makes sense if the second if were _inside_ the first if's body, doesn't it?

Comment: Thanks for commenting guys, I cannot put the second API call inside the first if statement, as the second API call should only be done if the first API call succeeds. Assigning a dummy value though, is an option :)

Comment: @FluffyBike so it isnt even possible to just put the entire second if in the first if?

Comment: Why would something like this not work for you: https://dotnetfiddle.net/sjA6HZ ? Sorry, this is better: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Q1I6zp

Comment: The error "Use of unassigned local variable 'result'" should come first if you didn't put the second if inside the first.

Comment: ^^ You wouldn't even need `result` if ... => https://dotnetfiddle.net/oCgneM or even https://dotnetfiddle.net/ijBgHV

Comment: @shingo I was asking that myself as well. Another issue I see here is that the Programm needs to be told what to do if SomeCondition does not apply. Like a return or something. If you "tell" the programm that it can only get to the second if, once it has tried the thing to set the value then the error will go away

Comment: @Fildor tbf this feels more like an example code rather then what it might actually look like. But What we KNOW is that myStruct and result can only be set IF `SomeCondition` applies, so its strange to me that the code is written in a way where it tries to use either of thoose values even if the first if may not be triggered

Comment: @SMSTJ Either way, OP could expand the last one I posted to whatever they _actually_ have and avoid that problem entirely.

Comment: @SMSTJ I just realized that both `result` and `myStruct` are fields. But `CS0170` should only be reported when you try to access a field from another class, so I believe that key information is missing.

Comment: @shingo oh yeah you are right

Comment: At this point @FluffyBike I think we need a bit more info. Since this very much seems to NOT be the actuall problem code but a quick example. I think we do need the information, how your class/method actually looks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code shouldn't compile, because `result` is uninitialized if the condition is not met.

```
MyStruct myStruct;
bool result;

if (someCondition)
{
    result = API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct);
}

if (result) // <-- never initialized if someCondition == false
{
    result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
}
```

You want to nest the second if inside the first if block (it makes the relationship between the blocks clearer as well):

```
MyStruct myStruct;
bool result;

if (someCondition)
{
    result = API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct);
    if (result)
    {
        result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
    }
}
```

With the latter, the scope of the variables can be further reduced to:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    MyStruct myStruct;
    bool result;

    result = API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct);
    if (result)
    {
        result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
    }
}
```

and eventually removing the need for changing result's value:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    MyStruct myStruct;

    if (API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct))
    {
        bool result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
    }
}
```

and with "newer" C# versions:

```
if (someCondition)
{
    if (API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out var myStruct))
    {
        bool result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your first example wont compile either wont it? Like at least for me it doesnt since myStruct still gets marked.

Comment: @SMSTJ the first example is a copy of the question

Comment: No. I was not talking about the first set of code but about your first example. So the one where you start with `bool result = false`

Comment: @SMSTJ ah well, I don't have a compiler at hand. I thought that should work. Thanks for the pointer, I have removed it

Comment: tbf I would have made that assumtion as well without an compiler

Answer (score 2):

Ok so this might be a dumb idea, but since I assume that if the call doesnt suceed there is no use in continuing the function / method couldnt you to

```
if (SomeCondition)
{
    result = API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct);
}
else
{
    return;
}

if (result)
{
    result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
}
```

Or as Fildor pointed out

```
if (!SomeCondition)
{
    return;
}

result = API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct);
if (result)
{
     result = API.AnotherCall(myStruct);
}
```

OR you do some nesting

```
if (SomeCondition())
{
    result = SomeThirdPartyCall(out myStruct);
    if (result)
    {
        result = AnotherCall(myStruct);
    }
}
```

OR you take a look at any of the other very good answers that have been posted^^

The main problem is that you let your programm get to the second if even if the first if isnt fired.

Comment: IDE would probably suggest to turn that into `If (!SomeCondition) return; ... `

Comment: @Fildor Honestly yeah

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid those warnings and shorten your code by using [short circuiting 'and's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-):

```
if (condition && API.SomeThirdPartyCall(out var myStruct) && API.AnotherCall(myStruct))
{
// Do what you need to do with the struct here
    Console.WriteLine("Do Something with {0}", myStruct);
    // For example: assign it to a class field / property
}
```

Example I posted in comments before: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ijBgHV

The second condition will only be evaluated if the first evaluates to true.
The third condition will only be evaluated if the second (and the first, therefore) evaluate to true.
So for the body to get executed, the "happy path" must apply. And only then.

Comment: Isnt that a bit "too" compressed? Since they ask for another result I assume some more stuff could happen after that and maybe also a if(!result) path. I mean I will give you that it looks neat, but wont it make it dificult if you for example want to do more/this seems like it isnt suited for upscaling. I dont know if you get what I mean BUT if things stay like OP presented them to us this is defenetly a VERY VERY good way.

Comment: What is also interesting is a thing that shingo pointed out in the comments under the OP. `CS0170 should only be reported when you try to access a field from another class`.

Comment: Please note `myStruct` is not a local variable, it's a field. I'm afraid you were also misled by the question.

Comment: _"Isnt that a bit "too" compressed?"_ - a matter of taste, basically. Just _one_ way to it. I am not claiming it to be the most readable or efficient or whatever.

Comment: @shingo OP can set that field from within the conditional body, right?

Comment: @Fildor oh sorry if I came of wrong. I wasnt talking from a readability standpoint, But from a "how easy is it to upsacle this/Add diverging paths to this" standpoint

Comment: @SMSTJ Fair enough. Yes, I guess, you'd have to reconsider then if you want or can keep that structure. You can always "break out" the last condition into a nested if, quite easily, though. I don't like nesting, especially if there are no "else" branches, so I tend to go for this if there is a situation of "only do X if happy path (n conditions all apply) and nothing (or something else) if at least one of them fails".

Comment: @Fildor I mean you can't get a CS0170 error in this way, the question may not be what you see.

Comment: @shingo Oh I see what you mean. Well, I can only _answer_ what I _see_. But point taken. Will monitor and adjust answer if OP edits the question.

Comment: @Fildor yeah the biggest issue in answering questions sometimes, is that people dont actually copy paste/give us the relevant ACTUAL code, but instead create a quick exaple (usually in a texteditor) and then make some extra mistakes in that/make similar reproduction impossible